# Are there studies about software ergonomics with data glasses?

Tags: wearables, software-engineering, google-glass, virtual-reality

I saw [this post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49551/what-would-generic-usability-heuristics-for-wearables-be-like) about usability heuristics for wearables.

Since such devices seem to be tech trendy, if I may say, I assumed there would be some studies about ergonomics with A-R glasses, yet I can't seem to find any real studies on the matter.

Are there such studies?

EDIT

This question was more about software ergonomics than about ergonomics with wearables *per se*, please read comments for more clarification.

Comment: PS: Funnily, all three tags were created by the question I referred to, and I'm the second use of them, ever.

Comment: What is it *specifically* you need to know about these glasses? Questions need to be based on a particular problem you have that needs solving, so just asking for general ergonomic studies is a bit broad. Can you define the actual issue you have and we can help you with answers to that.

Comment: @JonW: Actually I'm working on mock-ups for a glasses software, and most controls I'm used to using are unavailable (buttons for instance!). In website building we have *Jakob's law* which states that most users spend most of their time on *other* websites than yours, whereas with glasses, I feel like a pioneer of glasses software interfaces and have a feeling my decision should be based on actual studies rather than my mere intuition. How would you edit the question to make this need clearer?

Comment: Google might have published some kind of guide / research, but I think this is just too new an area for the academics to have jumped on the bandwagon. I would say just keep the the underlying biology of the visual system, and the general rules of usability in mind (e.g. don't overuse movement as it will distract the user), and usability test the hell out of everything you make. Someone always has to be first, why not you? :)

Comment: @ArlaudPierre I've tried to reply in more detail, in my answer, but even given your comments, I cannot determine which aspect of this you're trying to focus upon.  I think you need to give revision a shot, or ask another question on this topic.

Comment: Also, be aware that after lots of comment-chat, the comment may be flushed.  Best to update the question body with recently-developed pertinent details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many studies in VR and immersive contexts.

Check the (Association of Computing Machines) [ACM's VR group](https://www.google.com/search?q=ACM&oq=ACM&aqs=chrome..69i57.323j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=ACM%20vr) for associated info, name, conferences, and journals.

Probably the first line of work on immersion in the natural world (not a made-up VR) is [Steve Mann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Mann).  You can [read his pubs, and pubs about him, here](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=steve%20mann%20&btnG=&as_sdt=1,33&as_sdtp=).

---

### "Hands-free" Buttons

Re-reading the comments more (you really should update the question) I see that you're concerned with UX and ergo for interfacing apps / functions.

Keep in mind that 'ergo' in the broader context could mean situational usage (e.g. should your surrounding environment impact what data / UX is presented via glass / headset)

I suggest you look into [audio interfaces](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=audio%20interface%20&btnG=&as_sdt=1,33&as_sdtp=), generally, until you can refine your question further.

---

Happy hunting, and feel free to ask more questions (so this one doesn't become a 'forum') and @mention me in a comment.

Comment: Yeah sorry the comments differed much to what was in the question (on a side note, I never know what to think of people saying "you should really update it" when they have both the knowledge and power to do it themselves, not saying that for you or anyone in this topic in particular). I'll accept the answer as the Steve Mann reference was interesting, although he doesn't really talk about UX and software ergonomy. Thanks!

Comment: @ArlaudPierre No, specifically I will not update the the routes for restructuring are ambiguous.  I have my point of view(s), and updating the question, in this case, would have meant that I would have introduced my own bias.  I could not safely have 'revealed more of your inherent meaning,' which is possible in other cases.  It has to be you, here, else we would be best to turn the question into a community wiki

Comment: I can understand that, although I really wouldn't mind having your own bias added to the question.